# What should I do in Amazon AWS to auto scale, with new instances, containing the WAR file and Tomcat server as it is in first instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have my first instance in AWS EC2. It has tomcat deployed, configured and .war file of my web app. 
I went through the videos of Amazon AWS auto scaling, Elastic Load balancer etc.

My question is, when Ec2 creates new instances once it has meet the critical conditions (user defined CPU usage etc.), will the newly spun instances have war file and tomcat deployed (I mean cloned of first instance) or one should manually deploy and configure those???

Comment: One common approach is to bake Tomcat and its pre-requisites into the AMI that you launch from. Then you would deploy your app's WAR file after launch, using CodeDeploy or userdata scripts.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an auto-scaling group you specify the AMI to use for new instances. You can either create a custom AMI from your current instance and tell the auto-scaling group to use that, or you can pass a script via `user-data` that sets up each new server after it boots up.

If you make changes to your original instance, those changes will not be automatically copied to the newer instances. I would suggest using Elastic Beanstalk as it will manage a lot of this for you and all you have to do is push your application changes to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will now read on Elastic Beanstalk. What I was looking for was some directions and thanks for that.

Comment: I mostly plan to go with Elastic Beanstalk. Any idea how Docker can help here?